# Google App Engine dispatch.yaml Unexpected attribute 'service'

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml, dev-appserver

I am having some trouble getting my dispatch.yaml file to run on the local devappserver. I have had two errors one seems to be related to indentation 
`expecting <block end>, but found ?` I can fix this by removing the indentation as shown below in my dispatch file.

The second problem happens when I have removed the indentation I get `Unexpected attribute 'service' of type DispachInfoExternal` I have tried copying the [example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/dispatchref) from the google docs but I get the same error, I have also tried changing the name service to module as I believe that was the old name and I get the same error. I am using Atom as my editor.

```
dispatch:
- url: '*/content/*'
service: default

- url: '*/admin/*'
service: admin-services

- url: '*/creator/*'
service: creator-services

- url: '*/social/*'
service: social-services

- url: '*/subs/*'
service: subscription-services

- url: '*/user/*'
service: user-services
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the indentation from the [yaml files](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html).

It's different writing

```
dispatch:
- url: '*/content/*'
service: default
```

than

```
dispatch:
- url: '*/content/*'
  service: default
```

Comment: Ah I see was looking at indentation as a whole not line by line, seeing the google example didn't notice there was indentation there just thought it was as a block.